# Pegar uma variável em JS e passar para uma classe em PHP usando Ajax com Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Preciso criar um projeto que consome uma api com dados em json, criei a interface, mas na hora de pegar o resultado e enviar para uma classe no php, mas quando eu aperto o botão enviar, não acontece nada. No que eerrei? vi alguns posts sobre isso, mas não consegui sair desse problema, sou iniciante, e gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão.

```
<nav class="grid-12 header_menu">
   <form class="pesquisa-cidade" method="post" action="">
      <input id ="cidade" name="cidade" type="text">
      <input id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" class="btn">
   </form>
</nav>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#enviar").click(function(){
         var cidade = $('#cidade').val();

         $.post("",{cidade: cidade}, function(data){
           console.log("Sucesso: "+data[0]);
         },'json').error(function(){
             alert("Erro!");
         });
     });
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que você já tenha essa classe PHP implementada e que tenha algum método como `tratarCidade()`, por exemplo. Neste caso, se você ainda não está trabalhando com rotas e controladores (e eu imagino que não), deve haver um arquivo de ação que receba os dados do formulário e invoque o método da sua classe. Chamaremos este arquivo de `cidade.action.php` e ele terá a seguinte aparência:

```
<?php
    include('MinhaClasse.php');
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $objeto = new MinhaClasse();        
    $resposta = $objeto->tratarCidade($cidade);

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($resposta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

O primeiro cabeçalho permite que requisições sejam feitas a partir de qualquer origem. Abaixo, estamos imprimindo a resposta em JSON para que você não tenha problemas ao tratar os dados do outro lado com JavaScript.

O primeiro parâmetro do método `$.post()` deve ser a URL da sua aplicação onde você fará o tratamento da requisição e invocará o método da sua classe PHP. Neste caso, o próprio `cidade.action.php`:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#enviar").click(function(){
         var cidade = $('#cidade').val();

         $.post("http://localhost/seuprojeto/cidade.action.php",
             {cidade: cidade}, function(data){
           console.log("Sucesso: "+data[0]);
         },'json').fail(function(){
             alert("Erro!");
         });
     });
 })
```

Você também disse que nada acontece quando você aperta o botão enviar. Observe que a ação padrão de um elemento `input type="submit"` envia uma requisição HTTP e faz com que sua página seja atualizada. Para prevenir a ação padrão do botão, seu `.js` poderia ficar assim:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     });


     $("#enviar").click(function(){
         var cidade = $('#cidade').val();

         $.post("http://localhost/seuprojeto/cidade.action.php",
             {cidade: cidade}, function(data){
           console.log("Sucesso: "+data[0]);
         },'json').fail(function(){
             alert("Erro!");
         });
     });
 })
```

Comment: Dai nesse caso, eu estou usando o servidor do php embutido, e estou rodando na porta 8080, ficaria $.post("http://localhost:8080/cidade.action.php",?

Comment: Porque eu coloquei o nome do projeto antes do arquivo cidade.action e está dando erro

Comment: Se você usa o servidor embutido, não há necessidade de utilizar o nome do projeto, desde que esteja navegando a partir do diretório do projeto. Imagino que esteja.

Comment: Está dando  seguinte erro: uncaught error $post(...) e tá apontando a linha },'json').error(function){

Comment: Troque `.error` por `.fail`.

Comment: Parou o erro, mas dai ele retorna o alerta com erro, eu subi o servidor na raiz do projeto

Comment: Adicione `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` ao seu `cidade.action.php`, acima do outro `header()`. Talvez você esteja tendo dificuldades com CORS.

Comment: Eu havia criado uma classe chamada WeatherClient, e fiz o método tratarCidade() e criei a variável privada $cidade, dai passei ela como argumento no método e mudei no cidade.action, dei o nome da classe, porém ele dá o seguinte erro:Cannot read property '0' of null, e aponta para o array no ajax, não imaginava que essas coisas fossem tão difíceis rs

Comment: Seu prolema agora é no lado do servidor. A implementação da sua requisição Ajax está feita. Vá testando trechos menores de código, retornando valor por valor até descobrir qual é a variável que está nula e por quê. Boa sorte.

Comment: Beleza então mano, muito obrigado mesmo, vou precisar abraço!

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro argumento do $.post é o endereço da sua request, mas você está passando apenas uma string vazia.
Teria que ser algo do tipo "localhost:3000/cidades/". Verifique em qual port está o seu servidor, e qual o id do seu web service, e coloque-os no endereço.

Comment: Nesse caso eu passo o endereço da porta, mas e o parametro do textbox?
 var cidade = $('#cidade').val();
 $.post("http://localhost:8080/cidade", function(data, status){
       alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 });
               

     })